# An explicit form for the co-BRST operator?

Tags: operators, gauge-theory, constrained-dynamics, brst, ghosts

Take a theory with 1st class constraints $M_{\alpha}$. We gave ghosts $c^\alpha$ and their conjugates $b_\alpha$ for every constraint. The BRST operator $\Omega$ has ghost number $+1$ and has an expansion in powers of $c$:
\begin{equation}
\Omega=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(c^{\alpha_1}...c^{\alpha_{n+1}}b_{\beta_1}...b_{\beta_n}\right)_W~M^{\beta_1...\beta_n}_{\alpha_1...\alpha_{n+1}}
\end{equation}
where $(\cdot)_W$ is the [Weyl ordering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767550/weyl-ordering-of-fermions). The operators $(-i)^{n}M^{\beta_1...\beta_n}_{\alpha_1...\alpha_{n+1}}$ are self-adjoint.

W.r.t. the 'indefinite inner product' (or 'physical inner product' in the language of https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0201124), $c^\alpha$ and $b_\alpha$ are self-adjoint, making $\Omega$ self-adjoint.

W.r.t. the positive-definite inner product, however, (supposing it exists), the adjoint of $\Omega$ is known as the co-BRST operator $^*\Omega$ (which I suppose has ghost number $-1$). Is there an expression for $^*\Omega$?

Answer (score 0):

From https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.64.2863 it appears that, w.r.t. the positive-definite inner product, $c^\alpha$ is the adjoint of $b_\alpha$. Therefore $^*\Omega$ is
\begin{equation}
^*\Omega=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(c^{\beta_1}...c^{\beta_n}b_{\alpha_{1}}...b_{\alpha_{n+1}}\right)_WM^{\beta_1...\beta_n}_{\alpha_1...\alpha_{n+1}} 
\end{equation}